# Google Scripts User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. Google Analytics

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

I am having issues with permissions while reading data from Google Analytics Demo Account to Google Sheets using Google Scripts.

### Here is my code:

```
var tableId = 'ga:54516992'; // this is the correct Analytics Demo Table ID
var optArgs = {
 'dimensions': 'ga:week, ga:year, ga:channelGrouping',              
 'sort': 'ga:year, ga:week, ga:channelGrouping',      
 'start-index': '1',
 'max-results': '250000'                     
};
var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId,'2015-01-01','2016-01-01',
'ga:sessions, ga:pageviews, ga:adCost', optArgs);

if (results.getRows()) {
  return results;
} 
else {
  throw new Error('No views (profiles) found in getreport');
}
```

### Here's the error message:

User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

### Here's what I have done already:

- Added Google Analytics addon on the sheet
- Enabled the Google Analytics API in the Advanced Google Services
- Enabled API and Services on Google Cloud Platform API Dashboard and noticed that all requests are returning with errors
- Created an OAuth 2.0 client ID type Web application
- Created an OAuth consent setting with the right Application name

### P.S.:

- I have another Google Sheet with almost the same code, done years ago, and I am trying to replicate that result in another account, so I know the script is supposed to run and the TableID is correct as well.
- I know about the API restriction for the Demo account and it does not apply since I have a script running in another Google Docs account.
- If I run the same code within my own Analytics data it is returning without results, which is about right, and it is not showing me that permission error.

Comment: Hi. I can see that you've not received any comments or suggested answers for your question. Have you resolved things, or are you still looking for assistance?